# How do I change my C++ language to compile in C++17

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I compile my project, it gets the error in this [image]

And this is because it compiled in the wrong C++ Language, I need it to compile in C++17, however when I look into

> project > properties > configuration properties
> There is no option to change C+ Language in the 2022 version of Visual  Studios.

Where did they move C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard part of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot see `C/C++` when you open `Project -> properties`, make sure that you have at least one source file. I had a similar problem a few days ago, and the cause of it was because I didn't have any source files in my project yet.

If this is not the cause of your problem, then are you able to see `Project -> properties -> C/C++`?

Comment: In VS 2017, VS 2019, and VS 2022 this setting is in *Project* -> *Properties* -> *C/C++ -> Language* -> *C Language Standard* when using Visual C++. If you can't see this property page, then you should check your installation (i.e. make sure you have the C++ workload installed).